Wix not installing new exe package after old package is removed
I am trying to uninstall SqlServer 2017 and install SqlServer 2022. It is uninstalling SqlServer 2017 but never installing the 2022.
I have a class named RemoveSql2017.cs that's as follows:
 public class RemoveSQL2017
    {
        const string UNINSTALL_SQL_2017 = "/Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=PHARMSPEC /FEATURES=SQL /QS /HIDECONSOLE";
        const string sqlFile = "DetachPharmSpecDB.sql";
        const string DB_INSTANCE = "PHARMSPEC";
        const int COMMAND_LINE_WAIT = 10000;
        private static WixBootstrapper _bootstrapper;
        const string registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\HIAC\PharmSpec\Database";
        const string subKeyValue = "DataPath";

        public RemoveSQL2017(WixBootstrapper bootstrapper)
        {
            _bootstrapper = bootstrapper;
        }

        public void Remove(string bootStrapFolder, string dataFilePath)
        {
            CreateDetachSQLFile();
            CopyFiles(dataFilePath);
            UninstallSQL(bootStrapFolder);
            DeleteDBRegistryPath();
        }
        public static void UninstallSQL(string bootstrapFolder)
        {
            try
            {
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Beginning UninstallSQL; bootstrapFolder=" + bootstrapFolder);
                Process process = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(bootstrapFolder + "//SQL2017//setup.exe", UNINSTALL_SQL_2017);
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Completing UninstallSQL; bootstrapFolder=" + bootstrapFolder);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Error in UninstallSQL:\n " + e.ToString());
                throw (e);
            }
        }
        public static void CopyFiles(string dataFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Beginning CopyFiles; dataFilePath=" + dataFilePath + "  tempDBFilePath=" + Globals.tempDBFilePath);
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(dataFilePath, Globals.MDF_FILE), Path.Combine(Globals.tempDBFilePath, Globals.MDF_FILE));
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(dataFilePath, Globals.LDF_FILE), Path.Combine(Globals.tempDBFilePath, Globals.LDF_FILE));
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Completing CopyFiles; dataFilePath=" + dataFilePath + "  tempDBFilePath=" + Globals.tempDBFilePath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Error in CopyFiles:\n " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
        public static void DetachDB(string sqlFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Beginning DetachDB; sqlFilePath=" + sqlFilePath);
                string command = string.Format("-S .\\{0} -E -i \"{1}\"", DB_INSTANCE, sqlFilePath);
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("sqlcmd", command);
                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                info.CreateNoWindow = false;
                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = info;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.Start();
                string outputD = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                if (proc.WaitForExit(COMMAND_LINE_WAIT))
                {
                    _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, outputD);
                }
                else
                {
                    _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Process timeout in DetachDb");
                }
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Completing DetachDB; sqlFilePath=" + sqlFilePath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Error in DetachDB:\n " + e.ToString());
                throw (e);
            }
        }
        public static void CreateDetachSQLFile()
        {
            try
            {
                string sqlFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), sqlFile);
                var sqlScript = new StringBuilder();
                sqlScript.AppendLine("GO");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysdatabases WHERE name = N'PharmSpecDB')");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("use PharmSpecDB");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("DROP SCHEMA PharmSpecUsr");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("DROP USER PharmSpecUsr");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("use master");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("EXEC sp_detach_db 'PharmSpecDB'");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("GO");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM syslogins WHERE name = N'PharmSpecUsr')");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("DROP LOGIN PharmSpecUsr");
                sqlScript.AppendLine("GO");
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sqlFilePath))
                {
                    sw.Write(sqlScript.ToString());
                }
                DetachDB(sqlFilePath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "error in CreateDetachSQLFile:\n " + e.ToString());
                throw (e);
            }
        }

        public static void DeleteDBRegistryPath()
        {
            try
            {
                using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
                {
                    RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(registryKey, true);
                    if (subkey != null)
                    {
                        subkey.DeleteValue(subKeyValue);
                    }           
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "error in DeleteDBRegistryPath:\n" + e.ToString());
            }
        }

I am calling this class as follows: I am able to see SqlServer 2017 getting uninstalled.
 if (Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["PreviousVersion"].CompareTo("3.5.99") <= 0 &&
               Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["SqlInstanceKeyFound64"] == "1")
                {
                    RemoveSQL2017 removeSQL = new RemoveSQL2017(Bootstrapper);
                    removeSQL.Remove(Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["DB2017SETUP"], Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["2017DBDataPath"]);
                    Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["OLDDBDATAPATH"] = Globals.tempDBFilePath;
                    Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["INSTALLSQL"] = "1";
                }

I have a SqlServer.wxi in which the registry keys and the exe file are as follows. Before removing SqlServer2017 this is what is in the registry,

SqlServer.wxi
<Variable Name="SqlInstanceKeyFound" Value="0"/>
        <Variable Name="SqlInstanceKeyFound64" Value="0"/>
<util:RegistrySearch
          Id="SqlInstanceKeyFound64"
          Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" Value="PHARMSPEC"
          Result="exists" Variable="SqlInstanceKeyFound64" Win64="yes"/>
        <util:RegistrySearch
          Id="SqlInstanceKey64"
          Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" Value="PHARMSPEC"
          Variable="SqlInstanceKey64" After="SqlInstanceKeyFound64" Condition="SqlInstanceKeyFound64" Win64="yes" />
        <util:RegistrySearch
          Id="SqlInstanceFound64"
          Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SqlInstanceKey64]"
          Result="exists" Variable="SqlInstanceFound64" After="SqlInstanceKey64" Condition="SqlInstanceKeyFound64" Win64="yes" />
        <util:RegistrySearch
          Id="SqlVersion64"
          Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SqlInstanceKey64]\Setup" Value="Version"
          Variable="SqlVersion64" After="SqlInstanceKey64" Condition="SqlInstanceFound64" Win64="yes" />

 <PackageGroup Id="SQL2022Express">
      <ExePackage Id="SQL2022Express"
              DisplayName="SQL Server 2022 Express"
              Cache="yes"
              Compressed="no"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="no"
              Vital="yes"
              DetectCondition="SqlInstanceFound64"
              InstallCondition="INSTALLSQL=1"
              Name="Redist\SQLEXPR_x64_!(loc.LANG).exe"
              SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\SQLEXPR_x64_!(loc.LANG).exe"
              InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS [SQLQUIET] /HIDECONSOLE /FEATURES=SQLEngine /UpdateEnabled=0 /INSTANCENAME=PHARMSPEC /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=Builtin\Administrators /SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE&quot; /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=[SAPASSWORD] /NPENABLED=1 /TCPENABLED=1 /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck"
              UninstallCommand="/Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=PHARMSPEC /FEATURES=SQL /QS /HIDECONSOLE">
        <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
      </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>

In the log it's showing the following:

[0EE8:0EEC][2024-11-08T14:09:13]i000: Setting numeric variable
'SqlInstanceFound64' to value 1
[0EE8:0EEC][2024-11-08T14:09:13]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceFound' evaluates to false.
[0EE8:0EEC][2024-11-08T14:09:13]i052: Condition 'SqlInstanceFound64' evaluates to true.
[0EE8:0EEC][2024-11-08T14:09:13]i000: Setting string variable 'SqlVersion64' to value
'14.0.1000.169'
[0EE8:0EEC][2024-11-08T14:09:13]i101: Detected package: SQL2022Express, state: Present,
cached: None
[0EE8:0EEC][2024-11-08T14:09:29]i052: Condition 'INSTALLSQL=1' evaluates to true.
[0EE8:0EEC][2024-11-08T14:09:29]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with
no dependency providers: SQL2022Express
[0EE8:0EEC][2024-11-08T14:09:29]i052: Condition 'INSTALLSQL=0' evaluates to false.


SqlInstanceFound64 variable was found, which is used in your DetectCondition to indicate that SQL Express 2022 was already installed. The bundle will not install something that already exists.
I think you need to search for a registry key (or something) that is unique to SQL Express 2022. What you're looking at right now seems to be set by many versions of SQL Express.
